disable SSL revocation function during crates index update in PIP install
When install maturin using pip with MSYS2 on Windows, I'm getting the following error. I'm behind company proxy with self-signed certs and want to disable the revocatin check.
Error
$ pip install maturin
Collecting maturin
Using cached maturin-1.7.4.tar.gz (191 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: maturin
Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [39 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build/lib.mingw_x86_64_ucrt-cpython-311/maturin
copying maturin/init.py -> build/lib.mingw_x86_64_ucrt-cpython-311/maturin
copying maturin/main.py -> build/lib.mingw_x86_64_ucrt-cpython-311/maturin
running egg_info
writing maturin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to maturin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to maturin.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to maturin.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.json' under directory 'src/python_interpreter'
adding license file 'license-apache'
adding license file 'license-mit'
writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
running build_rust
Updating crates.io index
warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.)
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.)
error: failed to get anyhow as a dependency of package maturin v1.7.4 (C:\software\tools\msys64\tmp\pip-install-p3sp9qf1\maturin_f61e9ec002ef44939486f704e01026e3)
  Caused by:
    failed to query replaced source registry `crates-io`

  Caused by:
    download of config.json failed

  Caused by:
    failed to download from `https://index.crates.io/config.json`

  Caused by:
    [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.)
  error: `cargo metadata --manifest-path Cargo.toml --format-version 1 --locked` failed with code 101
  -- Output captured from stdout:

  [end of output]

Cargo -Vv
$ cargo -Vv
cargo 1.73.0
release: 1.73.0
host: x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
libgit2: 1.6.4 (sys:0.17.2 vendored)
libcurl: 8.2.1-DEV (sys:0.4.65+curl-8.2.1 vendored ssl:Schannel)
os: Windows 10.0.22631 (Windows 11 Enterprise) [64-bit]
Rustc -Vv
$ rustc -Vv
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03) (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: cc66ad468955717ab92600c770da8c1601a4ff33
commit-date: 2023-10-03
host: x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
release: 1.73.0
LLVM version: 17.0.1
Tried setting CUR_CA_BUNDLE to nothing as well as crt file that contains self-signed cert chain.
Still getting same error.
